# Add,Replace and addToBackStack confusion

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Hi Guys i have a confusion while doing FragmentTransaction.Below is the detail.

I have four Fragments say A , B , C , D.

What i have done is :

first A (replace)

A --> B (add and addToBackStack)

B --> C (add and addToBackStack)

C --> D (replace and addToBackStack)

now when i am in Fragment D and press back button here is what the navigation follow when i press hardware back key.

D --> B --> B(nothing happens) --> A --> Quits the app.

i am not getting where Fragment C has gone even though i am adding it to back stack

Please help me on this.

[here is the link to my whole demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nyxixa07xridq2i/2CMblTH85M)

Comment: can you post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace a fragment defined statically in the layout file. You can only replace fragments that you added dynamically via a `FragmentTransaction`,or programmatically add the fragment to an existing ViewGroup.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace

Comment: But i am not replacing statically.I am replacing fragment D with C via FragmentTransaction Only.

Comment: i have edited the post with dropbox link of my  demo project.Let me know if you can access that.